# Zooming image on coordination with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, online-game

what I'm trying to develop is a kind of online minigame, but I'm stuck on the zoom part. In my case there will be an html image with scattered eggs which will be part of the image. The player will have to click on the eggs and on the javascript side I will have to put an event listener on the precise position of the egg on the image and then zoom in on that position.

My problems are two: first of all I have to find a way to put an event listener on a point (so I guess with coordinates) of the image that will remain unchanged if the window is resized; I then have to find a way to zoom in on that point in javascript. All the guides I found explained only how to zoom with the muose wheel and not by clicking on that specific point.

Some idea?

[here's an image of my game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anXhQ.png)

Comment: ok interesting concept, but if you want help from the people here at stack overflow, youll have to show some of your current work

Comment: (0) Use an image-map. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map (1) The mouse-wheel code is what you need, unless you want to do an animated zoom. That code will get the coordinates of the mouse and enlarge the image around this central point of interest. It simply uses wheel rotation to set the zoom level interactively. Here's some code I wrote 1/2 a teenager ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095824/how-to-draw-a-lens-like-circle-on-mouseover

Comment: thanks for the reply, i added an image, but i didn't write almost anything of code because I don't know where to start.

Comment: @enhzflep thanks but i need a zoom animation and i can't use the mouse-wheel

Comment: @fabiodelcarlo - you're welcome. Yes, I know you can't use the wheel. Doesn't matter - you've still got allmost all of the code in mouse-wheel zoomers. They update the zoom level inside the handler for scroll. After the zoom level is updated, the screen is redrawn. You'd do the same thing - with a minor change. When the button was clicked, you start an interval timer. Each time the timer fires, you change the zoom level and redraw the screen. Once either the desired zoom level is reached or the right number of steps taken, you kill the timer. :)

Comment: Of course, you could use a spline function to control the level of zoom over time. (Think ease-in, ease-out animations, where the speed of the zoom is not constant) If you can redraw in 10ms and have 100 frames a second, you could use currentStep/totalSteps as the time value (it will range from 0 to 1) You can then use this time value as the X-coord and the value returned by your spline function as a 0-1 value for controlling the zoom level. See here for an exampe of using splines like this: http://jsfiddle.net/enhzflep/XKzGF/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working proof of concept of how to catch the point clicking and zooming in on the desired point:

```js
const gameElement = document.getElementById("game");
const eggsUrl = "https://i.imgur.com/saXapYu.png";
const pointsUrl = "https://i.imgur.com/tFStOam.png";
const backgroundImageSize = "1";

let isZoomedIn = false;
let zoomCoordinates = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};
let zoomSize = "100% 100%";

const points = [{
    x: 40,
    y: 40
  },
  {
    x: 200,
    y: 200
  },
  {
    x: 360,
    y: 360
  }
];

function onGameClicked(event) {
  if (isZoomedIn) {
    gameElement.style.backgroundSize = "100% 100%";
    gameElement.style.backgroundPosition = "center";
    isZoomedIn = false;
  } else {
    const clickedElement = getClickedElement(event.clientX, event.clientY);
    if (clickedElement) {
      zoomedX = 200 - (clickedElement.x * 2);
      zoomedY = 200 - (clickedElement.y * 2);
      gameElement.style.backgroundSize = "200% 200%";
      gameElement.style.backgroundPosition = `${zoomedX}px ${zoomedY}px`;
      isZoomedIn = true;
    }
  }
}

function getClickedElement(clickedX, clickedY) {
  for (const point of points) {
    if (clickedX > point.x - 25 &&
      clickedX < point.x + 25 &&
      clickedY > point.y - 25 &&
      clickedY < point.y + 25) {
      return point;
    }
  }
}

gameElement.addEventListener("click", onGameClicked);

document.getElementById("eggs").addEventListener("click", () => {
  gameElement.style.backgroundImage = `url("${eggsUrl}")`;
});
document.getElementById("points").addEventListener("click", () => {
  gameElement.style.backgroundImage = `url("${pointsUrl}")`
});
```

```css
#game {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/tFStOam.png");
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 1s;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="game"></div>
<button id="eggs">Show eggs</button>
<button id="points">Show points</button>
```

**Open snippet in "Full page" to test it out**

EDIT: I've even added the eggs!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this is exacly what I was looking for. Only two question: the point are responsive on window resize? and there is a fast way to find the coordinate of the eggs from my image?

Comment: Right now, the points are not responsive on window resize, but that's because of the way I quicly created this proof of concept. It should be a good starting point for your game, and you will be able to adapt the implementation along the way.