# Trying to make a magnifying glass for html canvas that views cgm images

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm attempting to build a loupe for a cgm canvas viewing application. I am trying to draw the  main canvas containing a cgm image onto a smaller canvas that is blown up to create a zoom effect. I'm having an issue however overlaying the zoom canvas correctly it seems to be in the upper right corner. I want the circle to contain the part of tha canvas its over except enlarged to zoom.

Here is some example code for reference

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var ox = canvas.width / 2;
var oy = canvas.height / 2;
ctx.font = "42px serif";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
ctx.fillStyle = "#800";
ctx.fillRect(ox / 2, oy / 2, ox, oy);

function magnify() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
  var base64 = canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 0);
  drawing = new Image();
  drawing.onload = () => {
    var tcanvas = document.getElementById("tCanvas");
    var ctx1 = tcanvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx1.drawImage(drawing, 0, 0);
    let w = drawing.naturalWidth
    let h = drawing.naturalHeight

    let size = w / 4 // Size (radius) of magnifying glass
    let magnification = 2
    let r = size / magnification // Radius of part we want to magnify

    let px = w / 3.5
    let py = h / 4

    let tileCanvas = document.getElementById("tCanvas")
    tileCanvas.width = 2 * size
    tileCanvas.height = 2 * size

    tileCanvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(canvas, px - r, py - r, 2 * r, 2 * r, 0, 0, 2 *
      size, 2 * size)

    let pattern = ctx.createPattern(tileCanvas, "repeat")

    ctx.fillStyle = pattern

    ctx.translate(px - size, py - size)

    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.arc(size, size, size, 0, 2 * Math.PI)
    ctx.fill()
    ctx.strokeStyle = "orangered"
    ctx.lineWidth = 12
    ctx.stroke()
  }
  drawing.src = base64; // can also be a remote URL e.g. http://
};
```

```html
<canvas id="tCanvas" width=240 height=240 style="background-color:#808080;"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas1" width=240 height=240 style="background-color:#808080;"></canvas>
<p></p>
<button id="magnify" onclick="magnify();">Zoom</button>
```

Comment: Here 'go. Complete with wheel-controlled zoom level. I'd forgotten all about it. It's not physically accurate.That is to say - everything within the circle is magnified by the same amount. If you want one that curves straight lines, I can have a look for it.

http://jsfiddle.net/enhzflep/xsEVb/

Comment: Here's the thread that contains both the above solution and the better approximation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095824/how-to-draw-a-lens-like-circle-on-mouseover

Answer (score 1):

### Zoom on canvas

Not sure why you are converting the canvas to a data URL or why you use a pattern? Just render the canvas using `ctx.drawImage(`

### Example

The example below creates a copy of the canvas to zoom, and then renders the zoomed image on the left canvas (clipped to a circle) and the original on the right with a circle representing the zoomed area.

Move mouse over right image to zoom.

```js
canvas1.addEventListener("mousemove",mouseEvents);
const mouse  = {x : 0, y : 0};
function mouseEvents(e){
    const bounds = canvas1.getBoundingClientRect();
    mouse.x = e.pageX - bounds.left - scrollX;
    mouse.y = e.pageY - bounds.top - scrollY;
    magnifyImage(mouse.x, mouse.y, 2, imageToZoom, tCanvas, canvas1);
}
const tag = (tag, props = {}) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), props);
function copyImage(image) {
    const can = tag("canvas", {width: image.width, height: image.height});
    can.getContext("2d").drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    return can;
}

const ctx = canvas1.getContext("2d");
const w = canvas1.width;
const h = canvas1.height;

ctx.fillStyle = "#800";
ctx.fillRect(w * 0.2, h * 0.2, w * 0.6, h * 0.6);
ctx.fillStyle = "#850";
ctx.fillRect(w * 0.3, h * 0.3, w * 0.4, h * 0.4);

const imageToZoom = copyImage(canvas1);
magnifyImage(60, 60, 2, imageToZoom, tCanvas, canvas1);

function magnifyImage(magCenterX, magCenterY, zoom, src, destZoom, destCircle) {
    const w = src.width / zoom | 0;
    const h = src.height / zoom | 0;
    
    // draw source image with circle
    var ctx = destCircle.getContext("2d");
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, destCircle.width, destCircle.height);
    ctx.drawImage(src, 0, 0);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#FA0";
    ctx.lineWidth = 3;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(magCenterX, magCenterY, Math.max(w, h) / 2, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.stroke();
    
    // draw zoomed content
    ctx = destZoom.getContext("2d");
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, destZoom.width, destZoom.height);
    ctx.drawImage(
        src, 
        magCenterX - w / 2, magCenterY - h / 2,
        w, h,
        0, 0,
        destZoom.width, destZoom.height
    );

    // clip zoomed image
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(
        destZoom.width / 2, destZoom.height / 2, 
        Math.max(destZoom.width, destZoom.height ) / 2,
        0, Math.PI * 2
    );
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";

};
```

```html
<canvas id="tCanvas" width=240 height=240 style="background-color:#808080;"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas1" width=240 height=240 style="background-color:#808080;"></canvas>
<p>Mouse over right image to zoom</p>
```

Comment: You are totally correct as far as not needing a pattern. This solution is close but i was using the canvas on the side as reference and the zoom also in the circle. I realized my client needs a square instead but ive run into some issues regarding scrolling the image and mousedown/mouseup. If you have any insight on it I left a question ober here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72277826/magnifying-glass-scroll-and-mousedown-issue-html-5-canvas