# Implement a magnifying glass/area in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a pure JavaScript (no jQuery) magnifier for when I hover over an area on a visible IMG, allowing me to zoom in to a larger segment of the original (which may be scaled to fit the screen).

[I think] I can make it work for a small example image (one sized 220 x 346px) but when I try a larger (1239 x 1754px) one then it seems to only work when looking at the top left corner of the visible IMG.

Can anyone assist in correcting the code to make this work?

```js
let image = document.getElementsByClassName('visible')[0];
let mag = document.getElementsByClassName('zoomed')[0];

image.addEventListener('mousemove', showMag);

useImage(1);


function useImage(n) {
  if (n == 1) image.src = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/42/Letraset_Lorem_Ipsum.jpg/220px-Letraset_Lorem_Ipsum.jpg';
  if (n == 2) image.src = 'https://data.webarchive.org.uk/crawl-test-site/resources/documents/lorem-ipsum.PDFA1-a.png';
  document.getElementById('nm').innerHTML = 'Image ' + n;
  document.getElementById('notes').innerHTML = `${image.naturalWidth}/${image.naturalHeight}`;
}



function showMag() {
  const imageRect = image.getBoundingClientRect();

  let url = image.src;
  let bgi = 'url(' + url + ')';
  if (mag.style.backgroundImage !== bgi) mag.style.backgroundImage = bgi;

  const scaleX = image.naturalWidth / image.width;
  const scaleY = image.naturalHeight / image.height;

  // Position over the visible image....
  let hoverX = parseInt(event.clientX - imageRect.left);
  let hoverY = parseInt(event.clientY - imageRect.top);

  // Position over the zoomed view...
  const zoomedX = parseInt(hoverX * scaleX);
  const zoomedY = parseInt(hoverY * scaleY);
  mag.style.backgroundPosition = -zoomedX + 'px ' + -zoomedY + 'px';


  document.getElementById('notes').innerHTML = `<span>w/h=${image.naturalWidth}/${image.naturalHeight}</span> <span>hover x/y=${hoverX}/${hoverY}</span> <span>positioning = ${mag.style.backgroundPosition}</span> <span>scale=${scaleX}</span>`;

}
```

```css
.container {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

img {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.visible {
  width: 30%;
}

.zoomed {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: solid 1px red;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}

span {
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  border-radius: 9px;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<button onClick='useImage(1)'>Image 1</button>
<button onClick='useImage(2)'>Image 2</button>
<hr>

<div id='nm'></div>
<div class='container'>
  <img class='visible'>
  <img class='zoomed' src=''>
</div>
<div id='notes'></div>
```

Comment: Here's another similar question with a few answers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095824/how-to-draw-a-lens-like-circle-on-mouseover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two examples ahead: Magnifying area and the magnifying glass

### Magnifying area

The simplest way to implement a magnifying area is to:

- convert the pointer position inside the thumbnail into a normalized delta float value from `0..1`
- use that float delta value as the `background-position` **percentage**:  `deltaX|Y * 100 %`
- There's a caveat! Since the natural width or height of the original image can be smaller than the magnify area side, you need to switch the `background-size` from `"auto"` to `"cover"` inside an image's `"load"` event listener. This way, by using `cover` the browser will magnify the image on its own inside the zoom area, and the user can at least either view it a bit zoomed in (if a perfect square) or explore it vertically or horizontally - without any extra effort (code) from your side

Example (view it in *Full page*):

```js
// DOM utils:

const el = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);
const els = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelectorAll(sel);

// Task: Magnify:

const images = [
  "https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NsGq.png",
  "https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFhxw.jpg",
  "https://i.stack.imgur.com/1P0rL.jpg"
];

const elImgSource = el("#imgSource");
const elImgZoomed = el("#imgZoomed");

const useImage = (n) => {
  elImgSource.addEventListener("load", () => {
    const noFit = elImgSource.naturalWidth < elImgZoomed.offsetWidth || elImgSource.naturalHeight < elImgZoomed.offsetHeight;
    elImgZoomed.style.backgroundSize = noFit ? "cover" : "auto";
  });
  elImgSource.src = images[n];
  elImgZoomed.style.backgroundImage = `url(${elImgSource.src})`;
};

const showMag = (evt) => {
  const imageRect = elImgSource.getBoundingClientRect();
  const pointerX = evt.clientX - imageRect.left;
  const pointerY = evt.clientY - imageRect.top;
  const deltaX = pointerX / elImgSource.width; // Normalize (0 to 1 float)
  const deltaY = pointerY / elImgSource.height; // Normalize (0 to 1 float)
  elImgZoomed.style.backgroundPosition = `${deltaX * 100}% ${deltaY * 100}%`;
};

// Events:
elImgSource.addEventListener("pointermove", showMag);

els("[data-useimage]").forEach(elBtn => {
  elBtn.addEventListener("click", () => useImage(Number(elBtn.dataset.useimage)));
});

// Init:
useImage(0);
```

```css
* { margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }

.container {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
}

#imgSource {
  display: inline-block;
  touch-action: none;
  align-self: start;
  width: 30%
}

#imgZoomed {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: no-repeat center;
  border: 1px solid #888;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button data-useimage="0">Lorem ipsum</button>
  <button data-useimage="1">Letraset</button>
  <button data-useimage="2">Sea</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <img id="imgSource" src="#!">
  <div id="imgZoomed"></div>
</div>
```

Extras:

- as you can notice I used the [`"pointermove"` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_events), to make it  handheld, touch devices friendly
- the magnified image is initially centered (which is nicer!) - and that's due to the CSS rule I used: `background: no-repeat center;`
- the images buttons use a `data-*` attribute where the image's array index is used. The images URLs are set inside that Array. On button click the index is read from the data attribute (`Element.dataset`). Much flexible and cleaner than using a complex `if (n == 2) image.src =` statements logic
- Don't use the `if (background was set)` logic. Simply set the zoom area background immediately on click, and if needed show (using CSS) the zoom area only on thumbnail `:hover`

### Magnifying glass

For the rounded magnifying glass that follows the mouse, here's another example:

```js
const el = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);
const els = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelectorAll(sel);

// Task: Magnify:

const elImg = el("#imgSource");
const elMag = el("#magnifier");
const radius = elMag.offsetWidth / 2;

const showMag = (evt) => {
  const imageRect = elImg.getBoundingClientRect();
  const pointerX = evt.clientX - imageRect.left;
  const pointerY = evt.clientY - imageRect.top;
  const deltaX = pointerX / elImg.width;
  const deltaY = pointerY / elImg.height;
  const x = deltaX * elImg.naturalWidth - radius;
  const y = deltaY * elImg.naturalHeight - radius;

  Object.assign(elMag.style, {
    backgroundPosition: `${-x}px ${-y}px`,
    translate: `${pointerX}px ${pointerY}px`,
  });
};

// Events:
elImg.addEventListener("pointermove", showMag);
elImg.addEventListener("pointerdown", showMag);
// Init:
elMag.style.backgroundImage = `url(${elImg.src})`;
```

```css
* { margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }

.container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
}

#imgSource {
  touch-action: none;
  max-width: 300px;
}

#magnifier {
  --radius: 60;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: calc(var(--radius) * 2px);
  height: calc(var(--radius) * 2px);
  margin: calc(var(--radius) * -1px);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

#imgSource:hover+#magnifier {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img id="imgSource" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NsGq.png">
  <div id="magnifier"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Roko - that seems to do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

The issue with your code is cause of the calculation of the zoom x and zoom y pos cause when u hovering over the larger image since the natural dimensions of the image are much larger than the displayed dimensions you need to take into account the offset of the visible portion within the larger image to fix this you should multiply the hover x and hover y coordinates by the ratio of the displayed image size to the natural image size additionally when calculating the background position for the zoomed image you need to take into account the offset of the visible image relative to the larger image I jus rewrote it below it should work now bud.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Magnifier</title>
    <style>
        .container {
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
        img {
            vertical-align: top;
        }
        .visible {
            width: 30%;
        }
        .zoomed {
            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
            border: solid 1px red;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 100%;
            background-color: grey;
        }
        span {
            background-color: #e8e8e8;
            border-radius: 9px;
            padding: 4px;
            margin-right: 10px;
            line-height: 30px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button onClick='useImage(1)'>Image 1</button>
    <button onClick='useImage(2)'>Image 2</button>
    <hr>

    <div id='nm'></div>
    <div class='container'>
        <img class='visible'>
        <div class='zoomed'></div>
    </div>
    <div id='notes'></div>

    <script>
        let image = document.getElementsByClassName('visible')[0];
        let mag = document.getElementsByClassName('zoomed')[0];

        image.addEventListener('mousemove', showMag);

        useImage(1);

        function useImage(n) {
            if (n == 1)
                image.src = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/42/Letraset_Lorem_Ipsum.jpg/220px-Letraset_Lorem_Ipsum.jpg';
            if (n == 2)
                image.src = 'https://data.webarchive.org.uk/crawl-test-site/resources/documents/lorem-ipsum.PDFA1-a.png';
            document.getElementById('nm').innerHTML = 'Image ' + n;
            document.getElementById('notes').innerHTML = `${image.naturalWidth}/${image.naturalHeight}`;
        }

        function showMag(event) {
            const imageRect = image.getBoundingClientRect();

            let url = image.src;
            let bgi = 'url(' + url + ')';
            if (mag.style.backgroundImage !== bgi) mag.style.backgroundImage = bgi;

            const scaleX = image.naturalWidth / image.width;
            const scaleY = image.naturalHeight / image.height;

            // Position over the visible image....
            let hoverX = parseInt(event.clientX - imageRect.left);
            let hoverY = parseInt(event.clientY - imageRect.top);

            // Position over the zoomed view...
            const zoomedX = parseInt((hoverX * scaleX) - mag.offsetWidth / 2);
            const zoomedY = parseInt((hoverY * scaleY) - mag.offsetHeight / 2);
            mag.style.backgroundPosition = -zoomedX + 'px ' + -zoomedY + 'px';

            document.getElementById('notes').innerHTML = `<span>w/h=${image.naturalWidth}/${image.naturalHeight}</span> <span>hover x/y=${hoverX}/${hoverY}</span> <span>positioning = ${mag.style.backgroundPosition}</span> <span>scale=${scaleX}</span>`;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your mousemove-translate offset is off. Translation should work like a virtual scrollbar. Instead, your zoomed image shows portions of gray background on one side bot not on the opposite, etc. Also there's again the same issue the OP came here in the first place. You did not tested your answer, did you?